# window.postmessage to a nested iframe in cross domain

Tags: html, iframe, cross-domain, postmessage

I have a root html page A (say A.html on foo.com) which contains an iframe B (say B.html on bar.com). iframe B contains another iframe C (C.html on foobarfoo.com).

I am trying to notify the iframe C when the user clicks something in the parent page A.

Since both the child iframes (B and C) are on different domains than the parent A, accessing the iframe property or calling a script is not an option.

I have control on the code in A.html and C.html and can use html5 postmessaging option to send messages. I tried sending postmessage from A to B which works fine, but sending it directly from A to C is something I am struggling with.

If I try to access the nested iframe C using document.parentWindow.frames, I just get only iframe B and not iframe C. Is this expected?

If I first get iframe B from DOM and then try to get iframe C by using getElementByID, I get access denied error which is obvious given that iframe B is on a different domain and querying its DOM wont be allowed.

Here is the code for both the options which I tried ...

**Option1**

```
function postMessage1()
{
    var message = new Object;
    message["MessageId"] = "NewPage";
    var messageData = JSON.stringify(message);

    var domain = 'http://localhost';
    var allFrames = document.parentWindow.frames;
    var iframe = allFrames['frameC'];

    iframe.postMessage(messageData, domain); -----> iframe is null here as it cannot find any frame with the ID - frameC.
}
```

**Option2**

```
function postMessage2()
{
    var message = new Object;
    message["MessageId"] = "NewPage";
    var messageData = JSON.stringify(message);

    var domain = 'http://localhost';
    var proxyFrame = document.getElementById("frameB");
    var targetFrame = proxyFrame.getElementById("frameC");  ----> Access denied to getElementByID in frame B as it is from a different domain and accessing its DOM is not allowed.

    targetFrame.contentWindow.postMessage(messageData, domain);
}
```

I am trying to find if there is a solution to this using window.postMessage. Any help appreciated.

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is access iframe C using a reference from the frames property of iframe B. So, basically, you recursively access the frames property of A to get B, and then access the frames property of B to get C:

```
function postMessage()
{
    var message = new Object;
    message["MessageId"] = "NewPage";
    var messageData = JSON.stringify(message);

    var domain = 'http://localhost';
    var iframeB = document.parentWindow.frames['frameB'];
    var iframeC = iframeB.frames['frameC']; // or iframeB.frames[0]; if C is the only iframe in B

    iframeC.postMessage(messageData, domain);
}
```

Haven't tried the above code out, but this kind of traversal through the tree of iframes is possible since the frames property does not fall under same origin policy.

Comment: I'm sitting on the same. While your code is correct in that it returns the foreign window element, I'm not able to use `postMessage` on it. Probably because I can only access `window.frames["local"].contentWindow.frames["foreign"]` when I would need the foreign `contentWindow` to postMessage to. Any idea if this accessible at all?

Comment: @frequent When you say that you aren't able to use postmessage on the window -- what exactly do you mean by that? Does the method throw an error (and if so - which error), or is the method not available? In any case, invoking a method on a "grandchild" iframe should be possible since it doesn't matter where in the hierarchy the iframe is, only that you can navigate to it using the `frames` property. + Do you perhaps have an example page that you are using to demonstrate the error? It'd be easier to debug.